# Get the last available value that meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame composed of two initial columns : one column of analysis called "Analysis 1" and one column of numbers associated to those analysis called "Number 1"

| Date (DD/MM/AA) | Number 1 | Analysis 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 80 | 51 |
| 02/01/21 | 81 | 52 |
| 03/01/21 | 83 | 53 |
| 04/01/21 | 82 | 54 |
| 05/01/21 | 83 | 55 |
| 06/01/21 | 84 | 56 |

Then I add another column full of numbers that looks like this. I call it "Number 2".

| Date (DD/MM/AA) | Number 1 | Analysis 1 | Number 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 80 | 51 | 80 |
| 02/01/21 | 81 | 52 | 80 |
| 03/01/21 | 83 | 53 | 81 |
| 04/01/21 | 82 | 54 | 81 |
| 05/01/21 | 83 | 55 | 81 |
| 06/01/21 | 84 | 56 | 82 |

What I want to do is to create a new column called "Analysis 2". In this column, I'd like to have the last available analysis (contained in Analysis 1) that corresponds to the number in "Number 2".

For example :

-Row 1 : the last available analysis for the number 80 is 51 so I write 51 in my new column.

-Row 3 : the last available analysis for the number 81 is 52 so I write 52 in my new column.

-Row 6 : the last available analysis for the number 82 is 54 so I write 54 in my new column.

This should look like this :

| Date (DD/MM/AA) | Number 1 | Analysis 1 | Number 2 | Analysis 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 80 | 51 | 80 | 51 |
| 02/01/21 | 81 | 52 | 80 | 51 |
| 03/01/21 | 83 | 53 | 81 | 52 |
| 04/01/21 | 82 | 54 | 81 | 52 |
| 05/01/21 | 83 | 55 | 81 | 52 |
| 06/01/21 | 84 | 56 | 82 | 54 |

I tried to use `mask()` based on a condition where Number 1 is equal to Number 2 but it doesn't work. Indeed, as you can see, this condition is not always met.

Do you have any idea to solve my problem please ? Hope it is clear enough.

EDIT : I tried to build a fonction that looks like this :

```
def analyse_correction(analyse_nc,analyse_corrected,number):
    df[analyse_corrected]=df[analyse_nc].mask(df['Number 1']!=df['Number 2'])
    df[analyse_corrected].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
    df[analyse_corrected].fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
```

The problem with this function is that the condition I'm using is not always met.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  We fix a problem in existing code; we do not write code from scratch: that’s your responsibility.

Comment: What if you had 83 in Number 2? Which Analysis 1 do you pick?  53 or 55?

Comment: @Prune I will gladly post my code tomorrow. I do not have it available for the moment but will surely do it.

Comment: @ScottBoston If 83 is in Number 2, I will take the last available value so 55 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mapper = df.drop_duplicates('Number 1', keep='last').set_index('Number 1')['Analysis 1']

df['Analysis 2'] = df['Number 2'].map(mapper)
df
```

Output:

```
  Date (DD/MM/AA)  Number 1  Analysis 1  Number 2  Analysis 2
0      2021-01-01        80          51        80          51
1      2021-02-01        81          52        80          51
2      2021-03-01        83          53        81          52
3      2021-04-01        82          54        81          52
4      2021-05-01        83          55        81          52
5      2021-06-01        84          56        82          54
```